# Order entries, exclude 'the' from order criteria

Tags: templating, ordering, mysql

I know this is partly a Twig question, but I've poked around quite a bit here, in Twig docs, Craft docs, and cannot find the right syntax.

I have a bunch of entries with titles like:

- Hotel A
- Grand Hotel B
- Zither Hotel Grand Plaza
- The Top Hotel

I want to order by title, alphabetical, but I need to exclude leading 'The ' from the order. I've tried this, but it barfs.

```
 {% for entry in craft.entries.section('hotels').order('(CASE when title LIKE 
'%The ' THEN LTRIM(title, 4) ELSE title END )') %}
```

Comment: How does it barf?  Is there an error message?  Also, pretty sure the LIKE should be `'The %'`, since you want to it start with `The ` and match anything after it.

Comment: I get  

`Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "string" of value " THEN LTRIM(title, 4) ELSE title END )" ("punctuation" expected with value ","). `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little tweak, and double quotes needed around the thing it is LIKE.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('hotels').order('(CASE WHEN title LIKE "The %" THEN SUBSTRING(title, 3) ELSE title END ) asc') %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Completely untested, but try something like this:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('hotels').order('(CASE WHEN title LIKE 'The %' THEN SUBSTRING(title, 4) ELSE title END )') %}
```

MySQL's [LTRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_ltrim) isn't what you want because that just removes leading spaces.  `SUBSTRING` should do it, though.

Also, keep in mind this is a MySQL specific query.  If you ever planning on running on PostgreSQL (that the Craft 3 beta supports), it would have to be adjusted.

Comment: Now I get  `Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "name" of value "The" ("punctuation" expected with value ",").` Can I pull all the entries into an array and use Twig to filter? If so, is there an example available? Thanks.